# Localhost returning "Undefined" rather than the unique ID

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to write a script that will return a unique ID from a database when clicked.  I've tried reading through different forums to find a solution but unfortunately, I've yet to find anything of use.

```
<?php
          $table  = mysqli_query($conn ,'SELECT * FROM content');
          while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $row['uidContent']; ?>">
              <td width="200" data-target="themeContent"><?php echo $row['themeContent']; ?></td>
              <td width="300" data-target="visualIdeaContent"><?php echo $row['visualIdeaContent']; ?></td>
              <td width="600" data-target="captionContent"><?php echo $row['captionContent']; ?></td>
              <td width="100" data-target="dateContent"><?php echo $row['dateContent']; ?></td>
              <td width="200" data-target="visualContent"><img src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>"width="200"/></td>
              <td width="170">
                <a class="badge badge-primary p-2" role="button" data-target="linkContent" href="<?php echo $row['linkContent']; ?>" target="_blank">Link</a>
                <a class="badge badge-success p-2" href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['uidContent'] ;?>">Edit</a>
                <a class="badge badge-danger p-2" role="button" href="action.inc.php?delete=<?php echo $row['uidContent'] ;?>" >Delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php }
          ?>
```

The unique ID is stored in this line of code through "data-id"

```
<a class="badge badge-success p-2" href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['uidContent'] ;?>">Edit</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){
    alert($(this).data('uidContent'));
  });
});
</script>
```

I expect localhost to return the unique ID **(For example, "localhost: 2066")** but instead, it's returning the result **"localhost: undefined"**...
At first, I thought it was an issue with my database, but now I've learned that it cannot be the case because the unique idea is displayed when I inspect the button in question. [Screenshot of the IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4O5O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data parameter should be `data('id')`. Use `$(this).data('id')` instead of `$(this).data('uidContent')`.

> jQuery [**.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) takes the argument after the **-** separator. For example: if an HTML attributes is `data-id="localhost: 2066"` then to get this attribute value we have to call like `$(selector).data('id')`.

**Example code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]', function() {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
    //                ^^^^^^
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="badge badge-success p-2" href="#" data-role="update" data-id="localhost: 2066">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Your solution worked. I feel incredibly stupid now. Huge thank you to you and the other individuals who help people like myself!

Comment: @JarelAntoine Glad to help you :)